# Print list on a single line from a pipe

Tags: perl, awk

I have a list of PCs and I need to append quotes and commas to each of them so that I can do a SQL query

List example

```
Row1|PCName|PC1.local
Row2|PCName|PC2.local
Row3|PCName|PC3.local
```

and I need to get this

```
"PC1.local", "PC2.local", "PC3.local", ......
```

Here is what I tried

```
cat list.txt | awk -F\| '{print $NF}' | perl -e 'while(<>){ print "\"$_\", ";}'
```

I get this

```
", "PC1.local
", "PC2.local
", "PC3.local
", "
```

How can I make those PCs show up in a single line and with the format that I need?

I know using awk or perl might be overkill for this and it could be done using Perl alone or awk alone, but I'm interested in learning how to pipe things to Perl. How can I make Perl print those PC names in the format I need?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print join ",", map { chomp; '"'.(split /\|/)[2].'"' } <DATA> ;

__DATA__
Row1|PCName|PC1.local
Row2|PCName|PC2.local
Row3|PCName|PC3.local
```

Output:

```
"PC1.local","PC2.local","PC3.local"
```

As a one liner:

```
perl -e 'print join ",", map { s/\n//; q{"}.(split /\|/)[2].q{"} } <>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'|' '{printf "%s\"%s\"", (NR>1?", ":""), $3} END{print ""}' file
"PC1.local", "PC2.local", "PC3.local"
```

Answer (score 0):

with unix toolset

```
$ cut -d'|' -f3 file | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | paste -s -d,
```

extract third field, wrap with quotes, join with comma

Comment: It needs to be `paste -s -d, -` (with a `-` for stdin instead of a file name) on OSX at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl one-line solution

```
$ perl -le 'print join ", ", map { /([^|\s]+)$/ && qq{"$1"} } <>' myfile
```

#### output

```
"PC1.local", "PC2.local", "PC3.local"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!perl 

use strict;
use warnings; 

while ( my $line = readline(*STDIN) ) {
   chomp $line;
   my @machines = split /\|/, $line;
   print join(',', map { '"' . $_ . '"' } @machines), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat list.txt | perl test.pl 
"Row1","PCName","PC1.local"
"Row2","PCName","PC2.local"
"Row3","PCName","PC3.local"
```

Comment: That isn't the output the OP is asking for.

Comment: I was demonstrating the quoting logic, limit the number of machines should be an easy extension for the OP